# p4 revert - file(s) not opened on this client but p4 opened reports otherwise

Tags: version-control, perforce

I am trying to revert a file from my perforce client.

p4 opened shows that the file is opened but p4 revert fails with error that it is not opened in this client.
I even tried /build/apps/bin/p4 opened -C  and it shows the concerned file.

What am I doing wrong? I am new to perforce. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the full transcript from the command line?  (Copy and paste the text from the terminal window, don't screenshot!)

Comment: I'm guessing that there's something like a typo where the path you're giving to `p4 revert` isn't the same file that's being reported by `p4 opened`.

Comment: @Samwise: you are right! The path had a problem. Could you please add your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Could you add the output of the commands you ran so I can use them in my answer to show how to spot the typo?  :)

Comment: @Samwise: I can't paste the exact output as it's something work related. But it basically has "main" in the file path of the depot. I removed the main and it worked.